# How to find disparity when camera is moving forward/backward only

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

When camera is moving forward/backward, I think stereo rectification would not work. I guess I have to search along the epipolar line directly. Currently, my only clue is to use LineIterator to iterate through epipolar line, and use its neighbors as descriptor. This is very unintelligent method. So I want to know if there is other ways, or helpful opencv functions.

Comment: https://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs143/lectures/13.pdf, my situation is on page 18, forward motion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old problem - Mark Pollefeys had a nice solution for it about 18 years ago. The idea is to rectify in polar coordinates.

See [his short paper](https://cs.unc.edu/~marc/pubs/PollefeysICCV99.pdf) and [lecture notes](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~marc/tutorial/node99.html), and look around for tech reports from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with Scale Invariant Feature Transform (SIFT) maybe with this descriptor you could get the key-points and stabilize the image with some transformation function per frame.

[SIFT in Matlab](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html)